# Echo in php from xml

Tags: php, echo

I am reading xml file with

```
<area>this this</area>
```

Read with the PHP code:

```
$xmlhotels = array(); 
foreach ($filtered as $hotel) {     
    $xmlhotels[] = array(        
      'area'=>(string)$hotel->area,
      // assume other stuff here...
    );
}

echo"
",$villa['area'],"
";
```

The echo result I get is:

```
this this
```

I need to have echo:

```
this+this
```

Comment: [`urlencode()`?](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: By the way - I edited your indentation and tried to make the code make sense visually...

Comment: You want to escape the space into a `+`/`%20` or you want to sum the two numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what little info I you provided I have no idea what your full objective is.

Assuming you ONLY want to replace spaces with + signs, use

```
echo"
",str_replace(' ', '+', $villa['area']),"
";
```

Answer (score 1):

If by `this+this` you mean you want to perform a escape in the space, you may use `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()`:

```
echo urlencode($villa['area']);
// prints this+this
```

If by `this+this` you mean you want to sum the two numbers, you can use this:

```
echo array_sum(explode(' ', $villa['area']));
```

But if you mean you want to get the square area from two side dimensions, you actually need a multiplication:

```
$temp = explode(' ', $villa['area']);
echo $temp[0] * $temp[1];
```